# How do i make the program exit by entering 0

Tags: python-3.x

```
# ABC Inc., Gross Pay Calculator!
# Enter employee's name or 0 to quit : Nathan
# Enter hours worked : 35
# Enter employee's pay rate : 10.00
# Employee Name : Nathan
# Gross Pay: 350.0
# Enter next employee's name or 0 to quit : Toby
# Enter hours worked : 45
# Enter employee's pay rate : 10
# Employee Name : Toby
# Gross Pay : 475.0
# (overtime pay : 75.0 )
# Enter next employee's name or 0 to quit : 0
# Exiting program...
```

How do i make the input for 0 print "exiting program" then exit?

```
print('ABC inc., Gross Pay Calculator!')
name = input("Enter employee's name or 0 to quit:")
hours = float(input("Enter hours worked:"))
payrate = float(input("Enter employee's pay rate:"))
print("Employee Name:", name)
grosspay = hours * payrate
print("Gross pay:", grosspay)
if hours > 40:
print("(Overtime pay:", (hours - 40) * payrate * 1.5)
while name!=0:
    name = input("Enter next employee's name or 0 to quit:")
    hours = float(input("Enter hours worked:"))
    payrate = float(input("Enter employee's pay rate:"))
    print("Employee Name:", name)
    grosspay = hours * payrate
    print("Gross pay:", grosspay)
    if hours > 40:
        print("(Overtime pay:", (hours - 40) * payrate*1.5)
else:
    print ('Exiting program...')
```

Comment: `while name!="0"`. `input` returns strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Do not repeat code like that.  Instead use `while True:` and conditional `break` as the appropriate place.  This is the standard 'loop-and-a-half' idiom in Python.

```
print('ABC inc., Gross Pay Calculator!')
while True:
    name = input("Enter employee's name or 0 to quit:")
    if name == '0':
        print ('Exiting program...')
        break
    hours = float(input("Enter hours worked:"))
    payrate = float(input("Enter employee's pay rate:"))
    print("Employee Name:", name)
    grosspay = hours * payrate
    print("Gross pay:", grosspay)
    if hours > 40:
        print("(Overtime pay:", (hours - 40) * payrate * 1.5)
```

I would replace '0' in the prompt with 'nothing' and make the test `if not name:`, but this is a minor issue.